# Ring isomorphism, Unity is preserved

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am wondering that if I have a ring isomorphism, /phi going from R to R', where R is a ring with unity, how can I prove that R' is also a ring with unity? It seems to be very obvious so I don't know where to start.... Just tell me something to keep me going thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If $\phi:R\to S$ is a ring homomorphism, then 
$$ϕ(r)=ϕ(1\cdot r)=ϕ(1)\cdotϕ(r)$$ so $ϕ(1)$ is a unity with respect to $ϕ[R]$, which is a subring of $S$. So if $ϕ$ is surjective, then $ϕ(1)$ is the unity of $S$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b\in R'$. Since $\phi$ is a ring isomorphism, there exists $x\in R$ such that $\phi(x)=b$. Then $b=\phi(x)=\phi(1_R\times x)=\phi(1_R)b$. In fact, notice I did not use anything more than the surjectivity and the fact it is a homorphism!

Comment: Of course, that shows left identity. Can you do right side (follow the same idea).