# Does a ring isomorphism preserves the structure of a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The problem is the following one:

Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ a ring isomorphism. If A is a field, is B a field?

I think It's false, but I can't think of a counterexample, and if it's true I have no idea of how to prove it.

Comment: It's true. Try to use the given isomorphism $f$.

Comment: All ring properties are preserved by a ring isomorphism, in particular existence of inverses.

Comment: Isomorphism means the same structure, i.e. A is just different than B by the name of elements.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I saw that post, but that was an isomophism between unitary and conmmutative rings, so I thought the solution may be different because the hypothesis was different too.

Comment: @Bernard But a ring isomorphism preserves the structure of rings, such as the distributive property for the sum. A field, for example, also have inverse element for every element, or existence of unity element, and that is not necessary preserved by the ring isomorphism, right? If not, how can I prove that?

Comment: @puradrogasincortar I hadn't realised your rings weren't unitary and commutative. Anyway, the proof is basically the same : simply note that if $A$ is a field, then it is commutative and unitary, and these properties are also preserved by isomorphisms (for the unit, see : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610942/ring-isomorphism-unity-is-preserved?rq=1).

Comment: For me rings all have a unit element, and fields are commutative. If an element in  a ring  has an inverse, its image in the other ring also has an inverse, which is the image of the inverse of the former element.